# Referencing multiple files upload to DB with node.js

Tags: node.js, jquery-file-upload, multer

I can't understand how to save references (filenames) of multiple files upload to the database using Node.Js.

I'm using blueimp jquery file upload and multer middleware to perform a multiple files upload to the local storage (uploads folder).

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="images" data-url="/record/edit/#{record.id}" multiple>
```

app.js code:

```
//using multer to upload files
const upload_images = upload.fields([{ name: 'featured_img', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'images', maxCount: 8 }]);
//...
app.post('/record/edit/:id',  upload_images, recordController.postUpdate );
```

recordController.js code:

```
exports.postUpdate = ((req, res, next) => {
   Record.findById(req.params.id, (err, record) => {
      if (req.files ) {

        console.log('UPLOADED')
        // record.featured_img = req.files['featured_img'][0].filename; //=> working for single file

        // Now, how to make it work for multiple files?
        console.log(req.files['images'])
        record.images = "HOW TO SAVE THE INFO OF REQ.FILES TO DB?";
     }
```

console.log output:

```
UPLOADED
[ { fieldname: 'images',
    originalname: 'slippry-02.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\agaez\\Documents\\sanbox\\nodeApps\\theapp\\uploads',
    filename: '8mdnuacm1469201049450.jpg',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\agaez\\Documents\\sanbox\\nodeApps\\theapp\\uploads\\8mdnuacm1469201049450.jpg',
    size: 49798 } ]
POST /record/edit/578580b43c7a08601730cc06 302 26.654 ms - 82
UPLOADED
[ { fieldname: 'images',
    originalname: 'slippry-03.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\agaez\\Documents\\sanbox\\nodeApps\\theapp\\uploads',
    filename: 'yrnnzl9h1469201049467.jpg',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\agaez\\Documents\\sanbox\\nodeApps\\theapp\\uploads\\yrnnzl9h1469201049467.jpg',
    size: 49792 } ]
```

#### **Update**

I'm using MongoDB as database and mongoose as ODM

**More info:** Curretly, I'm using jquery file upload which is making 2 post request when I upload 2 images. Without jquery file uploads it makes 1 post req for all the images uploaded and I get the req.files a unique array (with all the files uploaded). How can I save that info to MongoDB?

recordModel.js

```
//...
  images: String,
//...
```

Comment: you need to include what database you're currently using and perhaps show some of your current db code.

Comment: I've updated with more info @Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'images' property looks just like a single String value, so if you are looking for just a comma separated string of URLs the easiest thing would be to just bring in Lodash and create the string like so:

```
record.images = _.map(req.files['images'], 'path').join(',');
```

That said, I think in reality you don't want just a single string, but instead you'd do well (I think) to define an ImageSchema that includes some or all of the information you're getting from `req.files`.  At minimum, I'd pull in the path and the mimeType, but other info could be useful to you, I don't know.  In any case, given that you have an ImageSchema defined, you could do:

```
const Image = mongoose.model('Image');
/* your upload stuff happens, and then */

record.images = _.map(req.files['images'], function(i){ return new Image(i);});
```

That assumes of course that you update your RecordSchema to be:

```
...
images : [ImageSchema]
...
```

Hope that helps.